# No Activity found to handle Intent{typ=andrid.intent.action.PICK}

Tags: java, android

Well, I can't recognize why the problem below show up. I created an `imageView` button that when it is clicked it should open gallery to choose an image. Although, it triggers the following problem:
`No Activity found to handle Intent{typ=andrid.intent.action.PICK}`. Take a look at the code I wrote.

```
private ImageView imgContainer
private Bitmap storedImg;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 100;
private Uri imgPath;
postTypes = view.findViewById(R.id.PostOptions);

try {
       imgContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.pressToUpload);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

imgContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");

                    intent.setType(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

postTypes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), postTypes);
                menu.getMenuInflater()
                        .inflate(R.menu.post_options, menu.getMenu());

                menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.txtOption:
                                imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.imgOption:
                                imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.vdOption:
                                imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                break;

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                menu.show();
            }
        });

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
        try {
            ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null && data.getData()!=null) {
                imgPath = data.getData();
                storedImg = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, imgPath);

                imgContainer.setImageBitmap(storedImg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

Is it a problem with `ACTION_PICK`? Before `ACTION_PICK` I tried `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` but the same issue was triggered. What does it need in order to open the gallery?

Comment: Did you run this through emulator?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine no, from my mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this, `ACTION_PICK` fails sometimes when the phone doesn't properly support it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```